# expecting IdClass mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have model in java that contain 3 primary key and `TokensPK` class show my primary key.

The`hbm.xml` file , tag `composite-id` show these PK and show relation between 2 class but i cant understand

```
public class UserTokens {
    private String userId;
    private String loginProvider;
    private String name;
    private String value;


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public String getLoginProvider() {
        return loginProvider;
    }

    public void setLoginProvider(String loginProvider) {
        this.loginProvider = loginProvider;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class TokensPK implements Serializable {

    private String userId;
    private String loginProvider;
    private String name;


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public String getLoginProvider() {
        return loginProvider;
    }

    public void setLoginProvider(String loginProvider) {
        this.loginProvider = loginProvider;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and this is my hbm.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="oauth.identity.IdentityModel.UserTokens" table="UserTokens" schema="dbo" catalog="BBB">

        <composite-id mapped="true" class="oauth.identity.IdentityModel.TokensPK">
            <key-property name="userId">
                <column name="UserId" sql-type="nvarchar(450)" length="450"/>
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="loginProvider">
                <column name="LoginProvider" sql-type="nvarchar(450)" length="450"/>
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="name">
                <column name="Name" sql-type="nvarchar(450)" length="450"/>
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>


        <property name="value">
            <column name="Value" sql-type="nvarchar(max)" length="2147483647" not-null="true"/>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and my ApplicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 ">



    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>UserTokens.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>


    </bean>
</beans>
```

I know table have 3 primary but i cant understand where is my fault.
When i want to create database with this model this give me an error and i cant resolve it

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1783) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:404) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1275) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1263) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:2.2.0.M3]
    at oauth.identity.IdentityApplication.main(IdentityApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$3.resolveMember(AttributeFactory.java:977) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory$5.resolveMember(AttributeFactory.java:1035) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AttributeFactory.buildIdAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.buildIdClassAttributes(MetadataContext.java:389) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.applyIdMetadata(MetadataContext.java:319) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1842) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1779) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Don't mix hbm.xml mapping and annotation mapping. Chose one of them. Also I personally am no fan of annotations on the getter/setter methods. I prefer to have them on the fields directly so there can happen no mistake to place them at the wrong place

Comment: Why do you even have a hbm.xml. You don't need that

Comment: Im new in java but as i know hbm.xml in Necessary. your mean there is way to create DB without  hbm.xml file ??

Comment: @sahraair hbm.xml is not necessary if you are using annotations. Use only one of xml based configuration or annotation based configuration for hibernate

Comment: my friends thanks for your helping. but when i remove the annotations it give me same error

Comment: Have you removed all the annotations from your entity? Share the exceptions you are receiving after code changes.  Also, share updated code.

Comment: I would recommend you to use annotations based configuration instead of xml based as its easy to use and maintain

Comment: @Abhijeet the error nothing changed when remove annotations. its same  error "Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping"

Comment: @sahraair share updated code

Comment: I update my code  and error but ApplicationContext and hbm.xml  is nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Update your entity as follow:

```
    public class UserTokens  implements Serializable{


    private String userId;
    private String loginProvider;
    private String name;
    private String value;


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getLoginProvider() {
        return loginProvider;
    }

    public void setLoginProvider(String loginProvider) {
        this.loginProvider = loginProvider;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Your entity class should implement Serializable. Also, replace followings in the mapping file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="oauth.identity.IdentityModel.UserTokens" >

        <composite-id >
            <key-property name="userId" column="UserId" />
            <key-property name="loginProvider" column="LoginProvider" />
            <key-property name="name" column="Name" />
        </composite-id>


        <property name="value">
            <column name="Value" />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: still not working. do u have example link to resolve similar problem ? or project in github ?

Comment: @sahraair try this. You can refer https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate-composite-key-mapping-example.html

Comment: I try it but still not work :( . i upload my example here : https://ufile.io/o3ifimuw if u can please fix it for me bro much thanx

Comment: thnx so much :)

Comment: One more thing why are you writing all these configurations in applicationcontext.xml if you are using spring boot?

Comment: @sahraair are you able to solve the with updated answer?

Comment: hi bro NO its drive me crazy im crying

Comment: It should have worked. It worked for me. Can you upload updated code

Comment: after many days try it work. i would be very thankful from you bro much thnx

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: in my pc in office when i put catalog and schema tag for my table in hbm.xml its work fine but in my home pc give me an error and say jdbc cant execute ....  something like that i dont think its the problem because its work fine in my office now i cant create table in specific schema. bro do u have whats account  ?

Comment: Are you able to access the database from your home?

Comment: today is friday and i at home but i dont have access to my pc in office